# Android gradle-experimental 0.2.0 add res and aidl

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm struggling to use external library in Android Studio 1.3, Gradle 2.5 and gradle-experimental plugin 0.2.0, required because of NDK.

I found some material [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) on how to change old gradle files which I've done, but can't find any other documentation documentation.

During my extensive search I managed to find out the changes for manifest but not for `res` and `aid`. Has anyone managed to find out what need to be changed or any useful documentation?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'
    }
}

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 19
        buildToolsVersion = "19.1.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "org.opencv.android"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 8
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
            versionCode = 3000
            versionName = "3.0.0"
        }
    }

    android.sources {
        main {
            manifest.source.include 'AndroidManifest.xml' // OLD manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.source.srcDir 'src'
            resources.source.srcDirs 'src'
            res.srcDirs = ['res'] // ERROR
            aidl.srcDirs ['src'] // ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

The errors are:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find property 'srcDirs' on AndroidLanguageSourceSet 'main:aidl'.
>
> Gradle sync failed: Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.model.AndroidLanguageSourceSet_Decorated'.

Comment: I don't know if it fixes your issue, but maybe try `res.srcDirs += ['res']`?

Comment: The error message is now the same as the first one. Thanks anyway.
`Gradle sync failed: Could not find property 'srcDirs' on AndroidLanguageSourceSet 'main:res'.`

Comment: Hm.. Looks like they are all of the same type now (AndroidLanguageSourceSet). So the same syntax might work for all:
`java.source.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'`, `res.source.srcDirs += 'src/main/res'`, `aidl.source.srcDirs += 'src/main/aidl'` (worked in my case)
`

Comment: It works! I remember trying exactly the same thing a day or two ago. Must have made some mistake (typo or forgot the += ). Thanks! You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some debugging with `println` shows that `java`, `res`, `aidl` are of the type `AndroidLanguageSourceSet`. They all have the same `source` property now, and `srcDirs` list inside that. You should be able to append your custom paths to the srcDirs property like:

```
android.source {
  main {
    java.source.srcDirs += 'src'
    res.source.srcDirs += 'res'
    aidl.source.srcDirs += 'aidl'
  }
}
```

Don't forget to use `=` in the new syntax to set the value and `+=` to append it to the list (in the old syntax just a whitespace was sufficient).