# Issue when migrating to Gradle Experimental 2.5 : no such method AndroidConfig

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

I have just updated my Android Studio setup to 1.3 (latest stable as of 31st of August 2015) and I need to use the latest NDK integration. My previous Android Studio version was 1.2.1 (stable as well).

Following [Google Migration to Gradle Experimental Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) I managed to easily adapt my various gradle scripts.

However, Gradle Sync fails with the following error :

```
Error:No such property: android for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor
```

**[Update 1 -> see below, error updated]**

When I attempt to `Make` the project, I obtain a little more detailed error :

```
Error:(17, 1) A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: model.android
   > No such property: android for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor
```

App refers to the main application code (with activities and other).

Using the feature `F4 > Jumping to Source`, it opens my `build.gradle` script from my `app` project.

This is the content of the aforementioned script :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application' // experimental

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 21
        buildToolsVersion = '22.0.1'

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "company.com.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 10
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"

            // NDK
            android.ndk {
                moduleName = "MyAwesomeJNILib"
                cFlags "-std=c99"
            }
        }
        android.buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
            }
        }
        android.productFlavors {
            // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
            // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
            create("arm") {
                ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi"
            }
            create("arm7") {
                ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
            }
            create("arm8") {
                ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
            }
            create("x86") {
                ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
            }
            create("x86-64") {
                ndk.abiFilters += "x86_64"
            }
            create("mips") {
                ndk.abiFilters += "mips"
            }
            create("mips-64") {
                ndk.abiFilters += "mips64"
            }
            // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
            create("all")
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-android-support:2.4.0'
    compile project(':bluetoothmanager')
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1'
    // Units Testing
    //androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12' // experimental
}
```

As you can see, there is nothing very fancy here.
But you might notice there is some unit testing setup :

```
// Units Testing
//androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12' // experimental
```

`androidTestCompile` could not be resolved while migrating to **GradleExperimental** so I modified following a solution I can no longer find (sorry) where I would simple put `compile` in stead of `androidTestCompile`.
This was the error :

```
Error:(71, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'androidTestCompile()'
```

I tried to compare one of Google's NDK sample (`hello-jini` for example) as provided in the aforemention guide and [available here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk).

Except the `packagingOptions` I could not find any differences that would be responsible for my awry. I tried to remove `packagingOptions` but that did not make a single change at all.

**[UPDATE 1]**

You will notice that the more detailed error message states that it's in line #17 which is where I declare my **native build settings**.
I fixed the error which was `cFlags` must be changed to `CFlags` and I added the `=` as required by the new version of Gradle.
This did help, the error does not appear anymore but changed for :

```
Error:No such property: android for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the first part.

BuildType, flavors... are outside the android block, but inside the model block.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application' // experimental

model {
    android {
         defaultConfig.with {

         }
     }

    android.ndk {

    }

    android.buildTypes {
            release {

            }
        }
    android.productFlavors {

    }
}
```

Comment: yes thank you !!! But what about packagingInfos ? Is it needed ? Anyway, so far I managed to make it work ! But ... debugging in C++ code does not work (breakpoints not being hit). Using Windows, and LLDB