# Error:No such property: android for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm trying to build my android project using NDK but when I change build.gradle file, android studio show me error and I can't sync gradle. Can you help me to fix this?
My dependencies

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

and my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myproject"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel 15
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 24
        versionCode 11
        versionName "3.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.myConfig")
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    ndk {
        moduleName = "name"
    }
    android.lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
    android.dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "onesignalId",
                                local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "projectnumber"]
    }
}
android.signingConfigs {
    create("myConfig") {
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword 'mypassword'
        storeFile file('mypath')
        storePassword 'mypassword'
        storeType "jks"
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32312074/593978

You have everything inside android{} block, whereas most of your entries should be outside of it. This might be causing your exception.